# How to go to File explorer, after searching something in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Issue reproduce:

1.open vs code
2.click on search icon at left side navigation bar
3.now the explorer icon hidden automatically.

How to disable "explore" hide automatically.

(I always press control + shift + E to get the explorer)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can have only one of the main activity bar views open at a time.  So Explorer or Search but both can't be open at the same time.  You can put the Search functionality into the panel (where terminal, problems, etc. are) - then both could be open at the same time.  Click the search icon and then right-click below the input panels and select "Toggle Search View Position".

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Right click on the left side nav bar and then check explorer.

attached screenshot.

[image]